# Windows permission error to delete joblibmem mapping folder in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, xgboost

I am trying to run a python code that performs XGboosting and I wanted it to run parallely to take less time in building a model. But I am facing this issue while running a code.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\<<username>>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\joblib_memmapping_folder_85680_9566857635\\85680-1746225537432-968de5958f0642829c37f0f09f0e8b00.pkl'
```

I have even tried running the anaconda prompt as an administrator. But it is of no use. As a workaround I have also tried what is suggested in https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/806 but even then I am facing the same issue.

Could you please advice?